# How do I get the Graphite webapp to (re)read what's currently coming from collectd?

Tags: graphite, collectd, statsd

I have collectd running the tail plugin and writing data out using the write_graphite plugin (via carbon). This seems to work. If I then change the tail plugin config (e.g. change the Regex or DSType), and restart collectd, graphite stops showing me anything at all.

What this really boils down to is, once I update collectd's config, what do I need to restart/change to make graphite pick up the new data?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure you're sending data? (Check collectd logs)
2. Is graphite receiving data? (error, create, update logs in `/opt/graphite/storage/logs/carbon-cache`)
3. Is it that the regex in your carbon's `storage-schema.py` is restrictive and doesn't have a rule to accept new schema?

If you could localize the problem, i could assist you by drilling into the specifics.